# Responses to Spring Boot Controller from remote server

Tags: java, spring-boot, batch-processing, remote-server

I am working with Spring Boot using Java, and have controller, to where should responses come, in batches, from a remote address (e.g. https://www.remote.com/). Is it possible to do that in Spring Boot, configuring `RequestMapping` in some way or doing something else?
For example, can it looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("https://companyname.in/cb/paymentResultCpiKit")
public class PaymentController {

}
```

I would very much appreciate any suggestion or advice about it, since i don't have clear picture how that could be done..
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Making the actual web service using Spring is a very different problem from deploying and hosting your app on some server and configuring DNS A-record / vanity URL.

Comment: Please check out the tutorials under the title: Test and Consume the API at https://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series